Azure DevOps pipeline and Release
In Azure DevOps, we could run pipeline to actualize the pull requests in the CI process.
There is still Release which will run pipeline in the CD process.
Could we use the pipeline to do the CD instead of using Release?
Could anyone tell me why would we need to use release?

Hi Joanmok, Happy to work with your again. Please go through the document shared by @RUI which provides more detailed differences in the YAML and Release pipelines. Thx for your time and sharing.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT, thanks for the tip.

Hi @Joanmok, Glad to help.

Classic pipelines are created in the Azure DevOps web portal with the Classic user interface editor. There is a clear separation between the building and deployment processes - for example, you can define a pipeline to build, test your code, and finally publish your artifact (binary) and then you can define a release pipeline to consume your binary (artifact) and deploy it to specific targets.
This separation (build vs release) no longer exists when using YAML pipelines - you can use a single YAML pipeline to both build and deploy your application, if you wish so.
So, in your particular scenario, and in case you're not doing it already, I'd recommend to create a YAML pipeline with all the steps you need to run as part of the pull request.
See YAML vs Classic Pipelines.

Hi, thanks for the answer. It means that when using release, it's easier to use the artifact from the CI process instead of doing yaml pipelines step by step. Am I right?

@Joanmok not sure if I understood your question - "easier" is relative. You can publish and consume artifacts in the same pipeline, e.g. using YAML.

Q: Could we use the pipeline to do the CD instead of using Release?
Yes, it's entirely possible to utilize a YAML pipeline for Continuous Deployment (CD) instead of a release pipeline. You can use the same or separate YAML pipelines to define workflows (stages, jobs, steps) for both Continuous Integration (CI) and CD. The choice between using a YAML pipeline or a release pipeline for deployment is up to your preference and the specific needs of your project. For deployment purposes within a YAML pipeline, I would recommend leveraging deployment jobs, as they offer more flexibility and integration with code repositories.
Q: Why would we need to use release?
While YAML pipelines and release pipelines can perform similar functions in many CD scenarios, there are notable differences in features and usability. YAML pipelines are closely integrated with the source code, requiring a .yml definition file within the repository. On the other hand, release pipelines, which use the Classic Editor, provide a more user-friendly, interactive experience for orchestrating workflows.
Additionally, YAML pipelines continue to receive new features and updates, such as the recently introduced Manually triggered YAML pipeline stages. Despite these advancements, release pipelines offer a useful feature: the ability to edit a specific release directly, allowing for targeted adjustments to a single deployment without affecting others.
In my experience, I've found YAML pipelines to be more versatile and commonly used for deployments. However, the choice ultimately depends on your project's requirements and preferences.
